# Upload a file in a form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, api, file

I want to upload a file by fetching api. However, my `formData()` returns empty.

```
var formData = new FormData();
data.append("file", file[0]);

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {...},
    body: formData
}

fetch("url", options)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(result => ... );
```

There is my form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit()}>
    upload file
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: I added a sample image to my answer and also replied to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
formData.set('file', file[0])
```

Comment: is it instead of `data.append("file", file[0]);` ?

Answer (score 0):

A way that you can see inside the formData is like this:

```
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
  console.log(pair[0]+ ', '+ pair[1]);
}
```

You can try:

```
var formData = new FormData();

for (var key in files) {
  formData.append("file", file[0]);
}
```

Here are two functions I have written before, inside my React.Component class:

```
var formData = new FormData();

handleFileUpload = files => {
  var chosenData = new FormData();
  var allFiles = [];
  for (var key in files) {
    if (!isNaN(key)) {
      chosenData.append("document", files[key].name);
    }
  }
  for (var pair of chosenData.entries()) {
    allFiles.push(pair[1]);
  }
  this.setState({ chosenFiles: allFiles });
  for (var obj in files) {
    if (!isNaN(obj)) {
      formData.append("document", files[obj]);
    }
  }
};

buttonClicked = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newData = [];
  var newFormData = new FormData();
  if (
    this.state.chosenFiles.length !== formData.getAll("document").length
  ) {
    newData = formData
      .getAll("document")
      .slice(-this.state.chosenFiles.length);
    for (var obj = 0; obj < newData.length; obj++) {
      newFormData.append("document", newData[obj]);
    }
    this.fileUploader(newFormData);
  } else {
    this.fileUploader(formData);
  }
};
```

In my render:

```
<div id="selectFiles">
<label id="docFileLabel" htmlFor="docFile">
    Upload
  </label>
  <input
    type="file"
    id="docFile"
    className="docFile"
    onChange={e => {
      this.handleFileUpload(e.target.files, e);
    }}
    multiple
  />
</div>
```

**Sample image:**

[image]

**Another sample image:**

[image]

Comment: What did you return for your `formData` ? Did you put that in your `body` ?

Comment: You can't see inside formData unless you do something like what I mentioned above by using formData.entries(). I'm basically adding the file name to the formData, files[key].name. I will add another sample function as well as an image sample to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

data.append("file", file[0]); should be **formData.append("file", file[0]);**

Comment: Short answers must be posted as comments. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer